# Minecraft mod help ironchest mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-industrialcraft

I installed ic2 buildcraft and the ironchest mod  but am unable to make a silver chest since none of these mods add silver . Is there any mod that adds silver that will work with iron chest except redpower (it is out of data).

Comment: Thermal Expansion and Factorization add silver

Comment: @ratchetfreak: suggest you make that an answer (with links to the mods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Thermal expansion as it is a good add on for IC2 and it will also add the silver you need.